# How do I get certain a property value from multiple objects using json?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this site:
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/
as ajax practice with javascript.

I'm trying to get a certain property value from multiple IDs.

Let's use phone for example.

How can I loop through all the files and get every id and his phone?

Like this:

id : 1
phone : 123

id : 2
phone : 124

I'm trying to use `for...in` but I can't really get the hang of it rather than looping through only 1 of them.

```
function callToServer(param) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      //if (this.readyState == (4) Done && this.status == (200) All good) {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        res = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for (var key in res) {
          demo.innerHTML += `${key} : ${res[key]}<br>`;
        }
      }
    }
// notice that I used "9" after to loop only through 1 :)
xhttp.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/9", true);
      xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: `res[key].id` and `res[key].phone`

Comment: You'll need to tell us what happened when you tried that

Comment: If you use `users/9` in the URL it doesn't return an array, it just returns a single object for that user ID.

Comment: as i commented, im trying to use it without the /9/ to loop trough all of them.

the answer is correct, i feel like stupid now because i wrote it the same way just didn't noticed that i didn't specify the key like:
res.value instead of res[key].value

Comment: thank you for your help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the array and get the `id` and `phone` properties of each element. You can use `forEach()` for this rather than a `for` loop. See [Why is using "for...in" for array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea?lq=1)

```js
function callToServer() {
  let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      let html = '';
      let res = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      res.forEach(user => demo.innerHTML +=
        html += `id ${user.id}: phone ${user.phone}<br>`;
      )
      demo.innerHTML = html;
    }
  }

  xhttp.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access your data using `res[key].id`

```
function callToServer(param) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        res = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for (var key in res) {
          demo.innerHTML += `${key} : ${res[key].id}<br>`;
        }

      }
    }
```

Comment: What about the phone number?

Comment: Same, replace `id` by the element you want like`res[key].phone`